# How to display a Paragraph field with a condition

Tags: theming, 8, paragraphs

Hello here is my problem, I have a paragrah type with an illimited value image field in which I store image(s) to display them in 200*200 but also a single Json file with mapping data linked to the image(s) in the paragraph.

But in the drupal conf I can not hide the json file name since it's stored in the same field, they would both be invisible (json and image).

However I'd like to display in the Frontpage view and so (/node/xxx) only the image(s) and not the json file name even though they are in the same paragraph field, is that possible directly in drupal configuration or do I have to make a template ?

Comment: json file stored in the same field??? maybe you meant to say same paragraph?

Comment: nono, my paragraph type has 2 fields, and in the second field which has illimited value configuration, there are images and a link to the Json content my_file.json. His content is not stored in the paragraph but the file name must not appear.

Comment: Why would you store both images and a json file in the same field? Use separate fields and then you can easily control what is shown when. You should properly structure your node and paragraph types, that's what makes it so powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how complex your logic is, you can either write it inside the paragraph preprocess function, as in:

```
function THEME-NAME_preprocess_paragraph_PARAGRAPH-TYPE($variables, $paragraph) {
  if(some_condition) {
    $variables['field_name'] = $paragraph->get('field_name')->value;
  }
  // ...
  return $variables;
}
```

or write the same logic inside twig template if its simpler, as in:

```
{# paragraph--PARAGRAPH-TYPE.html.twig #}

{% if condition %}
  {{ content.custom_var }}
{% endif %}
```

I can elaborate and edit this answer if you are more specific.

Comment: Thank you Badri, it seems link it's kinda the logic I'm looking for but in case I edited the question to be more specific about what is intended.

Comment: Btw , where should i put the function THEME-NAME_preprocess_paragraph_PARAGRAPH-TYPE ? in my xxx.module with my hook 'indesign_node_presave' or in the theme folder ?

Comment: It should be in your theme folder.

Comment: I ended doing a simple template, displaying all but the first array value.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  $paragraph = $variables['elements']['#paragraph'];
  $variables['image_position'] = $paragraph->get('field_image_position')->value;
}
```